# Practical precision for Options Pricing

Tags: options, trading, numerical-methods, best-practices

When pricing options, especially in the theoretical literature getting high precision, say up to 8 decimal places is always a competitive goal. Though realistically in a practical setting is such precision always needed? If prices are only quoted up to x decimal places (as a side what is the precision most prices are quoted up to, 5 dp?), do we actually only need to worry about precision up to this point, and any thing else is but academic?

Thanks

Comment: Note that a precision of 8 decimals on an on option price becomes of 2 decimals, hence up to the cent, when you buy 1 million of such options, so I guess it's all a matter of perspective.